# The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mono, castle

Since upgrading to NHibernate 3.2.0.400, Castle.Core 2.5 and FNH 1.2.0.712, whenever we start the application the following exception is throw:

> The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

The stack trace shows us that the error happens when Mono.Addins tries to initialize the addin engine.

```
[NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.]
   System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_CodeBase() +56
   Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.CheckHostAssembly(Assembly asm) +85
   Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.ActivateRoots() +44
   Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.Initialize(Assembly startupAsm, String configDir, String addinsDir, String databaseDir) +320
   Mono.Addins.AddinManager.Initialize(String configDir, String addinsDir) +49
```

The thing is I don't think this is a Mono.Addins issue - I ran up another project with just the NHiberate stuff, no Mono.Addins and I get the same error.

Refreshing the page gets rid of it and the application continues to run, but this is incredibly annoying for development, and obviously not good enough for production.

NHibernate was added via NuGet, as was FluentNHibernate.  Fluent was added using -IgnoreDependancies as it complained about the version of NHibernate that was installed.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - turns out this was Mono.Addins - reverting back to 0.6.0 got rid of this error.  Upgrading back to 0.6.1 introduced it again.

I think this bug was fixed for 0.6.0 and re-introduced into 0.6.1.  I'll continue this over at the MonoAddins group.